# IBM Websphere MQ Publisher Confirms and Consumer Acknowledgement, .NET client

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

Are the features below supported by IBM Websphere MQ in .NET client? Please provide code example.

**1. Publisher Confirms**

When Publisher sends messages to queue, it receives confirmations from MQ server that messages have been saved to hard disk.

Does MQ server save message before sending confirmation?

**Update 2**

Is it corrent that when MQQueue.Put() returns, the message has been saved to transaction log? How long does it take to save to disk? What about message persistence in a cluster?

```
     void PutMessage(byte[] messageString)
    {
        try{

            // creating a message object
            message = new MQMessage();
            message.Write(messageString);
            message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            message.CharacterSet = 1208;// IbmUtf8Encoding;
            message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;

            var options = new MQPutMessageOptions
            {
                Options = useSyncPoint ? MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT : MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT
            };

            queue.Put(message, options);
            qMgr.Commit();

        }catch(Exception e){
            qMgr.Backout();
        }
    }
```

**2. Consumer Acknowledgement**

When Consumer receives messages from queue, processes them, then sends acknowledgement to MQ server.

**Update 3**

How can Consumer acknowledges to MQ server that messages have been processed successfully, and the messages can be safely deleted from server?

```
public void GetMessages()
    {            
        Open(ConnectionMode.Read);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
        {             
            GetMessage();
        }
        queue.Close();
        queueManager.Disconnect();         
    }

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        message = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING };
        var mqMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {           
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
        };

        queue.Get(message, mqMessageOptions, MaxMessageSizeInBytes);

        var content = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
        message.ClearMessage();

        return content;
    }


public void Open(ConnectionMode websphereConnectionMode)
    {
        var connectionSettings = new Hashtable
        {
            {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
            {MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT }
        };

        int openOptions = 0;

        switch (websphereConnectionMode)
        {
            case ConnectionMode.Read:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
            case ConnectionMode.Write:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
        }
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
        queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
    }


    public enum ConnectionMode
    {
        Read,
        Write
    }
```

[How to do an explicit ACK when receiving Websphere MQ messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244701/how-to-do-an-explicit-ack-when-receiving-websphere-mq-messages)

Comment: You would need to commit for it to be finalized, when the commit returns it would have been written to disk. Messages stay persistent for the life of the message, so when hopping to other queue managers via classic or cluster channels it will be persisted to disk along the way.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would suggest you download MQ Advanced for Developers and try this stuff out yourself.  You have already modified your question to encompass what should have three different questions.  The original question as asked by you was answered by @AttilaRepasi.

Comment: You then modified it to ask a second more specific question which @Roger answered.  Now you have modified it to ask a third question, each of those should have been different questions, Stackoverflow is supposed to be one question/answer per post.

Comment: I did NOT change my original questions. There are questions related to question 1, for example it includes cluster, which needs clarifying. If it is easily answered, it would have been answered. These are valuable questions which are helpful for other readers.

Comment: You are welcome to provide answers though.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at  MQ Advanced for Developers.

Comment: MQ Advanced for Developers is just an MQ Server, which I has already had.

Comment: MQ Advanced for Developers is good for installing a "sandbox" local on your machine for development/testing.  If you already have a queue manager to test against, then I suggest you try your code out, if you have issues then come back and post a [mcve] specific to the issue you have.  You are much more likely to get a answer to a specific question than a very broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the message is persistent, then MQ will write it into the transaction log  and wait for the log extent to reach the disk, before put returns.
2. To achieve this, the consumer should read messages under syncpoint, and commit the gets after appropriate processing is done on the client side.

Comment: Do you mean once MQQueue.Put() returns, the message has been saved to transaction log? How long does it take to save to disk? What about message persistence in a cluster?

Comment: any link on  this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot find code example for point 2. Any idea?
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111260_.htm

Comment: Yes, if the message is set to be persistent (message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;) it is saved on disk before Put returns, so there is no need to wait for any confirmation. The same applies for clusters, your message will be persisted on the QM you connect to, and will be transmitted in a persistent manner across the cluster.

Comment: On cluster, double check, so messages will be saved to all servers in cluster before Put returns? In this case, Put might take a while to return?

Comment: On Cunsumer, do I still need to use Commit if my code is like Update 3? Please check my updated post.

Comment: 1 For Put(), you have to use Commit() explicitly or implicitly after Put() to guarantee message persistence. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: No, you don't have to use syncpoint to guarantee message persistence. It's enough to set the persistence property.

Comment: MQ clusters are load balancer clusters, so your message will only be delivered to one of the local instances of the clustered queues.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code is correct so far but you are missing either MQ commit or backout.  Your code needs to tell MQ that the UOW (Unit of Work) is complete or to undue it.
i.e.

```
qMgr.Commit();
```

or

```
qMgr.Backout();
```

Comment: How do I mark the beginning of unit of work? Please check my updated code to verify it is correct? Any code example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why is it that none of the IBM code example is using Commit() or Backout()? C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\    Does it mean all these examples are kind of Fire-and-forget delivery, except those using transaction?

Comment: The code doesn't look any different from when I posted 4 hours ago.   The UOW begins when you issue the Put() with the MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT option and ends with either commit or backout.  The whole point of using a UOW is that the code is doing 2 or more things that you want to tie together.  i.e. DB update & MQ put.  If you are not doing 2 different things then don't use a UOW.

Comment: There are at least two scenarios when publisher send message to a broker. 1 When publisher wants to know that broker has received messages, publisher hopes for the best (Fire-and-forget) 2 in addition to 1, broker has stored the messages, and publisher receives better message delivery guarantee. How can I code these scenarios?

Comment: First off, "for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)" is wrong.  You read messages until the MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE exception is thrown.  Secondly, you need training in MQ, so I suggest reading the Introduction to MQ RedBooks or take a course or go to MQ Technical Conference (it is very cheap training) http://www.mqtechconference.com

Comment: I guess your have done the training, or are more knowledgeable on this field. Do you have advice for my two questions above, especially question 2.